# Clock synchronization between Cortex-A9 and Cortex-M3

Tags: microcontroller, clock

I'm working on the synchronization between a Cortex-A9 and Cortex-M3 microcontroller. The Cortex-A9 is the master and is connected to the Cortex-M3 via SPI.

- How can the Cortex-A9 (master) and the Cortex-M3 (slave) have a synchronized clock? Should we use the PPS GPS signal? If so, how?
- Is it correct that when they are communicating via SPI, it makes it difficult to do clock synchronization?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to ask? You want the A9 and the M3 to use the same clock source for the processor clock? Or are you referring to an RTC, as suggested by your mention of a GPS clock? What is the goal?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

 yes exactly i am reffering to the RTC. i am in an intership and my boss told me that the A9 and the M3 should be synchronized. that the A9 should send the UTC clock to the M3 so that the M3 could adjust his RTC to ensure a good reception of the frame.
I don't know if you catch my words?

Best regards.

Comment: @user39665 Do you want to synchronize RTC units or do you just want to have data transfer over SPI? Or do you want to synchronize RTCs using SPI? If you want to synchronize RTCs over SPI, how precisely do they need to be synchronized?

Comment: @AndrejaKo thank you so much for your answer. yes i want to synchronize the two RTCs units and my boss told me that i should use the UTC clock do do that. and as i am a newbie in that i can't really understand how to begin and how synchronization will be done. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're a bit confused about what exactly you're supposed to do and are incorrect connections between things.

First, did you read up on [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC)? Basically, the GPS unit you have should output its time using UTC time zone and, as far as time synchronization is concerned, UTC is no longer of interest. You may want to translate from UTC to your own time-zone, but that's not related to clock synchronization.

Next, your Cortex A9 should receive the time and set its own RTC to the time sent by the GPS. In order to have as correct time as possible, it would be a good idea to use the PPS output of the GPS to trigger the procedure which will set-up the RTC time on the A9. This is where the "precision" comes into play. It takes some time for RTC to be set up and your RTC will be late by that amount of time. Usually, that won't be a problem, since the amount of time is very short, but some attention may be needed in order to be sure that nothing interrupts the time-adjustment process.

Finally, you have the problem of synchronization between the two microcontrollers. As far as I understand it, you want to transfer time from A9's RTC to the M3's RTC using SPI. SPI clock isn't too important here. A9 will send clock (not the wall clock!) and control the data transfer speed. Again, you'll have similar problem to setting up the RTC on A9. Transfer of data from the A9 to M3 takes some time and M3's clock will be late by that amount of time, unless you try to do something to avoid that (if it's worth doing in the first place).

So a way to do this is to adjust the A9's RTC so that its second passes as close as possible to the PPS signal of the GPS. Next, right after the PPS signal, initiate transfer from A9 to M3 in order to be as little late as possible.

How precise you can be also depends on the RTC timer itself. Some may allow you to pause their time count. This way, you can set up the time on RTC in advance and then count down the PPS from GPS until that time comes (for example, when it's 13:26:26, set the time to 13:26:27 and enable the RTC when 13:26:27 is counted by PPS). It will usually be faster to enable RTC than to set up its time. This way, you can be a bit closer to the actual UTC time, but the process will be a bit complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your response. here is how i see things: 
      •    The A9 capture the UTC clock at T0
      •    Generates an interruption to the M3
      •    When getting the interrupts the M3 memorizes the value of the timer T0DB and starts it
      •    When getting the UTC clock the M3 stops the timer at T1DB
      •    Synchronization is done at T0 + (T1DB - T0DB)  The precision should be +/-20 us and resolution should be 100ns

Comment: A minor nit, which could be important in high-precision applications: Most GPS receivers output "GPS system time", which is NOT identical to UTC. They were identical back in 1980, but since then, UTC has been adjusted by leap-seconds, while GPS time has not. They currently differ by 16 seconds.

Comment: @Dave Tweed ♦  Indeed! I was thinking about that while writing the answer, but I just decided to assume that the GPS receiver is actually outputting UTC, which may not be internally justified assumption.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. i face another problem here with the solution...generating interruption could have an effect in accurancy?

Comment: @user39665 Yes, interrupts will have an effect on accuracy. It takes some time for the processor to respond to the interrupt, once it's detected on pin. Then it takes some time for processor to reach interrupt service routine and then it takes some time for the ISR to be executed. Also depending on other processes on the system, the RTC interrupt may have to wait for an interrupt of higher priority to finish and it may be interrupted by an interrupt of higher priority. The processor datasheet may have more precise timing info in cycles for the above-mentioned operations.

Answer (score 1):

SPI communication is independent of system clock, you do not need to worry about synchronizing core clock, one will be a master and one will be a slave. Master will provide clock for the communication

Comment: Thank you for your response.

it means if we have two different RTC in cortex A9 and Cortex M3 this wont make a problem in synchronization and accurancy?

Comment: I wont start a second branch of conversation, I think @AndrejaKo asked a valid question, and I think you should change your question so that instead of using the word "Clock" you use "RTC". This should help

Comment: yes my problem is how to synchronize the RTCs. i think i should use the RTC word from the beginning.